# Will cutting a trench affect structural integrity of the foundation

Tags: electrical, concrete, foundation, slab, kitchen-island

I am renovating my kitchen and putting in an island, by the code an island must have an outlet. I will have to put a trench into my concrete slab foundation to make it happen. (To run the electrical).
From my research a go-to conduits is PVC which will require a trench of at least 2" deep. The slab foundations are 6" as far as I could google. I am concerned that taking off 1/3 of my foundation will affect its integrity.

Any thoughts there? How do people usually run electrical to islands sitting on concrete slab with no basement post construction? Is there a code that states max depth of the trench in the residential slab?

Comment: Do you know whether your slab is reinforced with steel rebar or is "post tension" ?

Comment: Not sure, it is residential slab with no basement and it is 20 years old. What do I mean by post tension

Comment: Generally the slab is not the foundation but just a pour that happened after the actual foundation was poured.  But since there are some types of foundations that incorporate the slab, you'll want to have a licensed structural engineer inspect and give you an assessment.  You're likely going to need this in order to get your building permit anyway.

Comment: Got it, I am looking to gather some info first to understand what is the strategy, since I am doing it myself

Comment: to add to Jim Stewart's point, read this: https://buyersask.com/articles-of-interest/post-tension-slabs-what-are-they/ if you think you might have poor soils in the area or anyone has mentioned "raft" foundations you should consider putting off slab work until you familiarize yourself with the subject. You can still work with post tension slabs, but it's a different game.

Comment: aside: If you put the island on heavy-duty lockable casters you (likely) won't need electricity, and it can be handy to move every now and then.